# JDBC Realm authentication with single table

Tags: glassfish, jdbcrealm

I tried to make jdbc realm authentication with single table, but it always redirect me to loginerror page.
Here is my settings:

Table (korisnici):

```
idkorisnika
korIme (it is username)
sifra (it is password)
tipKor (it is role)
```

Role type's are: admin, radnik and klijent
Password in database is hashed as SHA-256

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/rentacarDatasource" object-type="user" pool-name="jdbcRealmPool">
    <description/>
  </jdbc-resource>
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="jdbcRealmPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rentacar?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value=""/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>klijent</role-name>
    <group-name>klijent</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>radnik</role-name>
    <group-name>radnik</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>AdminConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>RadnikConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>radnik</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/radnik/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>radnik</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>KlijentConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>klijent</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/klijent/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>klijent</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description/>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/loginerror.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>radnik</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>klijent</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="RentacarPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/rentacarDatasource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

login form

```
<p:panel header="Login From">
            <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
                Username: <input type="text" name="j_username" />
                Password: <input type="password" name="j_password" />


                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
            </form>
        </p:panel>
```

Here is properties for jdbc-realm in glassfish console:

```
JAAS Context: jdbcRealm
JNDI: jdbc/rentacarDatasource
User Table: korisnici
User Name Column: korIme
Password Column: sifra
Group Table: korisnici
Group Table User Name Column: korIme
Group Name Column: tipKor
Password Encryption Algorithm: AES
Charset: UTF-8
```

Everytime when i try to log as any type of user it redirect me to loginerror.xhtml 
Can someone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not jsf related (besides the `p:panel` which could be removed and it would still fail)

Comment: i know it's not jsf, but i found on youtube some tutorial and follow every step and when i run it doesn't work, can you write me what is the problem or send link for another tutorial that will work

Comment: No, since I don't use glassfish... sory